# add tr by ajax if not exists

Tags: jquery, ajax

So this is my setup. I have a blank table and a button. When i hit the button, i will query my database via ajax and get a JSON back. I itterate trough the JSON and add rows to my table. However, the user can delete a table row. When he hit the button again i want to make sure only the deleted table is appended to the table.

This is what i have now HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id='tableBoodschappen'>

</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='opslaan' disabled>Opslaan</button>
```

This is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getData").click(function() {
        $.ajax({url: "ajax/htmlBoodschappen.php", 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){  
                if(result[0].voorraadID >0) {
                    var $append='';
                    $.each(result, function(i,item) {
                        if($("tr#"+item.productID).length==0) {
                        var aantal=parseInt(item.min)-parseInt(item.aantal)
                        $append+="<tr id='"+item.productID+"' class='voorraad data'>"
                            +"<td style='vertical-align: middle;width:60px' class='aantal'>"
                                +"<span class='aantal'>"+aantal+"</span>x "
                                +"<div class='btn-group-vertical btn-group-xs btn-group-hover' role='group' style='display:none'>"
                                    +"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary chevron-up-aantal'>"
                                        +"<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span>"
                                    +"</button>"
                                    +"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary chevron-down-aantal'>"
                                        +"<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>"
                                    +"</button>"
                                +"</div>"
                            +"</td>"
                            +"<td style='display:none' class='voorraadID'><input type='text'  id='"+item.voorraadID+"'></td>"
                            +"<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>"+item.artikelNaam+"</td>"
                            +"<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>"+item.artikelMerk+"</td>"
                            +"<td style='vertical-align: middle;'>"+item.inhoud+" "+item.type+"</td>"
                            +"<td style='vertical-align: middle;'><button type='button' class='close remove' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>"
                        +"</tr>";
                        }
                    });
                    $("#tableBoodschappen").append($append);                            $("#getData").prop("disabled", true);
                    $("#opslaan").prop("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    //alert('error');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So when i hit the button the table is altered. When i hit the x button, the tr is removed. But when i hit the add button again, it says that the removed row still exists. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array put in it your tr's ids and when the user delete on delete it also from the array and when click the button again check first if it exist in the array

Comment: This actually works perfect. stuppid i didn't think about it. Thanks a lot :D